# How can I omit the headers for a route when using Mojo?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

Mojo seems to want add headers to the response. Is there any method to suppress headers given a context object?

```
$r->get('/')->to( cb => sub {
  my $c = shift;
  # No headers for this response
} );
```

Comment: Why do you need to suppress the headers?

Comment: Because, I'm using `print "<body>foo</body>";` to generate a body, and that works fine. But then Mojo comes along later and after the body and adds HTTP headers. And that's not really useful.

Comment: Isn't there a suitable renderer instead of printing directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case, I was using [`Mojo::Server::CGI`](https://github.com/mojolicious/mojo/blob/master/lib/Mojo/Server/CGI.pm). You can see the problems [on line 29](https://github.com/mojolicious/mojo/blob/master/lib/Mojo/Server/CGI.pm#L29) and [on line 35](https://github.com/mojolicious/mojo/blob/master/lib/Mojo/Server/CGI.pm#L35)

```
return undef if $self->nph && !_write($res, 'get_start_line_chunk');
...
return undef unless _write($res, 'get_header_chunk');
```

You can get around this by mucking with the internals,

```
$c->res->content->_headers->{header_buffer} = '';                                                                          
$c->res->{start_buffer} = '';
```

But an even better way to is detect if anything has been written to STDOUT and to suppress the whole request if so,

```
# We withhold headers if anything has written to
# STDOUT. This is neccessary because some scripts, in-transition
# to Mojo will still use `print`, and output headers
if ( tell(*STDOUT) != 0 ) {
  return undef;
}
```

That what I did anyway when I published [Mojo::Server::CGI::LegacyMigrate](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/ECARROLL/Mojo-Server-CGI-LegacyMigrate-0.01/lib/Mojo/Server/CGI/LegacyMigrate.pm)